# Pandas Dataframe Indexing, Where

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe of wine data

```
wines_dict = {
'Appellation': list(wine_appellations),
'Ratings': list(wine_ratings),
'Region': list(wine_regions),
'Name': list(wine_names),
'Varietal': list(wine_varietals),
'WineType': list(wine_wine_types),
'RetailPrice': list(wine_retail_prices) 
}

wines_df = pd.DataFrame(
data = wines_dict,
columns =[
    'Region',
    'Ratings',
    'Appellation',
    'Name',
    'Varietal',
    'WineType',
    'RetailPrice'
    ]
)
```

I am trying to slice it using  `wines_df.where((wines_df['Ratings'] > 95) & (~pd.isnull(wines_df['Ratings'])))` but it is returning back `NaN` ratings still.

```
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3          NaN
4         97.0
5         98.0
6          NaN
```

How can i slice it so that it returns all the Non Null values that are greater than 95?

Comment: Don't use `where`. Use `wines_df[...]` to subset instead.

Comment: why not use where? I am confused. Huh Taking out the `.where` fixed the issue. But the docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html on where() shows it takes a boolean criterion.... So it should have worked shouldn't it?

Comment: Because the conditions not satisfying the boolean mask would result in `np.nan` so as to return a `DF` having the same shape as the original. The purpose of `where` & `mask` aren't for slicing/subsetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple slice like this should give you the desired output

```
wines_df[(wines_df['Ratings'] > 95) & (wines_df['Ratings'].notnull())]
```